# How do I weight variables with gower distance in r

Tags: r, distance, hierarchical-clustering

I am new to R and am working on a data set including nominal, ordinal and metric data.
Therefore I am using the gower distance. In the next step I use this distance with `hclust(x, method="complete")` to create clusters based on this distance.

Now I want to know how I can put different weights on variables in the gower distance.
The documentation says:

```
daisy(x, metric = c("euclidean", "manhattan", "gower"), stand = FALSE, type = list(), weights = rep.int(1, p))
```

So there is a way, but I am unsure about the syntax (`weights = ...`).
The documentation of `weights` and `rep.int`, did not help. 
I also didn't find any other helpful explanation.

I would be very glad, if some one can help out.

Comment: Don't forget to mention you are working with `library(cluster)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are getting at, but...

Let's say you have 5 variables, e.g. 5 columns in your data frame or matrix. Then `weights` would be a vector of `length=5` containing the weights for the corresponding columns.

The notation `weights=rep.int(1,p)` in the documentation simply means that the default value of weights is a vector of length p that has all 1's, eg. the weights are all equal to 1. Elsewhere in the documentation it explains that p is the number  of columns.

Also, note that `daisy(...)` produces a dissimilarity matrix. This is what you use in `hclust(...)`. So if `x` is a data frame or matrix with five columns for your variables, then:

```
d  <- daisy(x, metric="gower", weights=c(1,2,3,4,5))
hc <- hclust(d, method="complete")
```

**EDIT** (Response to OP's comments)

The code below shows how the clustering depends on the weights.

```
clust.anal <- function(df,w,h) {
  require(cluster)
  d  <- daisy(df, metric="gower", weights=w)
  hc <- hclust(d, method="complete")
  clust <- cutree(hc,h=h)
  plot(hc, sub=paste("weights=",paste(wts,collapse=",")))
  rect.hclust(hc,h=0.8,border="red")

}

df <- read.table("ExampleClusterData.csv", sep=";",header=T)
df[1] <- factor(df[[1]])
df[2] <- factor(df[[2]])
# weights increase with col number...
wts=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
clust.anal(df,wts,h=0.8)
```

[image]

```
# weights decrease with col number...
wts=c(7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
clust.anal(df,wts,h=0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I now have the problem, that I cannot see any differences in the dendrogram using this syntax. I even used extreme weights to see differences. Do I understand it correctly that the vector in `weights=c(1,2,3,4,5)` are the weights for each column? So weight 1 for column 1, weight 2 for column 2 etc. I tried this a couple of times, and I learned that the weights can not be an uneven number, and they cannot be higher than the number of columns. Otherwise I get _type$weights must be 1:ncol(x)_

Comment: The vector passed as weights must have length = number of columns in x, yes. But there's no restriction on odd, even. To go furtehr, I'd need your dataset. Can you post a link?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not give out the real data. I created a good example http://bit.ly/1gferLt Thank you for the effort!